# Symfony2 How to secure server side some fields choices in a form to avoid user modification

Tags: php, forms, security, symfony

I am searching for a server side way **to secure some entity fields choices in a form** in order that the user cannot change it before submitting the form.

**Context**

Imagine that I have a table with several teams and user of the website can add players in several teams according to their rights. When a user want adding a player in specific team, the server provide a form to fill player details. This form needs to transmit the team ID to the server to finalize the palyer creation.

Even if I specify the `read_only` attribute to the team entity, it it still possible to trick HTML to remove attribute and send another value of team ID to the server.

**Q : In the player form, how can I avoid user changing team entity field value?**

Also, the player adding process has been generated with CRUD Symfony command tool and imply that the form field details are filled with URL `www.mysite/route/new` and form submitting `www.mysite/route/create`.

In this case, even if I restrict the choice to 1 entity item in the `buildForm` function because I know the team ID to use with `www.mysite/route/new` (by passing paramter in url like this for example `www.mysite/route/new/1`) it will not to be the case when user will submit the form.

I really don't know how to proceed. At this time, I save the team ID value in a session variable and set it before form validation in create action.

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: I think you should check the permissions when processing the submitted data: even if a user tinkers with HTML, they cannot write things they are not permitted to.

Comment: @tzunghaor In Symfony, not necessarily. Form will be invalid if it contains fields that shouldn't be there (was messing with the HTML)

Comment: @IgorPantović you are right, Symfony check that the provided value is  part of possible choice. But I don't know how to filter the team to reduce to only 1 choice during the validation process (create url call)

Comment: @tzunghaor you are also right, but imagine that a user has the rights to add players in team 1 and 2. When user click to add a player in team 1, how can I force user to create a player in team 1 and not 2 even if user trick HTML? Sorry for the poor example.... it is more about security concern

Comment: @sdespont What is a security concern if he has permission to add to any of those? What does he gain by doing that?

Comment: @sdespont To me, it looks like you don't need **teamId** at all in the form. It should be in the url. (GET FORM: /team/15/player/new, POST FORM: /team/15/player). So fetch team by ID from url on POST action and check whether he has permission to add to that team. Everything else is unneccessary.

Comment: @IgorPantović yeah it is true... what about master the entire process of form submission?

Comment: @sdespont how do you mean "master the entire process" ?

Comment: Are you using the Symfony form system?  If so then mark the field in the Symfony form read only.  Won't matter what the user does.  The entity's property will not be updated.

Comment: @Cerad In fact, there is no verification server side when read_only is specified. I have just tried with Chrome, and it is possible to chose another value accepted by Symfony.

Comment: Then you don't have your form setup correctly.  Maybe post your code for a read only field.  Because I know for a fact that if you have marked your Symfony form field as read only then it will ignore any posted values.

Comment: Interesting.  Looks like there has been some debate over what read only means.  In any event, just set the disabled flag and you should be good to go: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#disabled and https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/1974

Comment: @Cerad I will post my code for review. With the disable parameter, Symfony is not taking into account the submitted value which means that it is useful for edit but useless to create a new entry because the team ID will never sent.

Comment: Yep.  In all but trivial cases you will want to use different forms for creating and editing.  Or else get tricky with telling the form which mode it is in.